# Which class contains the function that is fired when clicking OK-button?

Tags: aspx, reflection

In SharePoint 2010, under page settings its possible to do change language settings at "_layouts/muisetng.aspx".

I need to know which class contains the function that is fired when clicking the OK-button.

How someone please help me find the answear to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you're looking for class `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.LanguageSettingsPage` from assembly **Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.dll**, which can be found under following path:

> c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\CONFIG\BIN\Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.dll

There, you will need to investigate the **BtnUpdateMUISettings_Click** method.

Comment: Thank you omlin! I was blindly searching in the \14\ISAPI folder, witch was my error.